# Remove last row in CSV file

Tags: csv, power-automate

An automatically generated CSV file has an extra line at the bottom and is creating a problem in a Power Automate flow for me. I don't know how typical this is, but when opening the CSV in Notepad, each item is separated by 6 empty rows. The last item has 7 empty rows, which is what I believe the problem is. Can I delete that last row of the CSV file using Power Automate? I don't think I have access to Powershell, nor do I know how to use it.

Comment: maybe create a variable called lineCount count how many lines there are, and create a loop from 0 to (lineCount - 2). I did 2 since we start at 0. If you started at 1 you would do 1.

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain exactly how I would create that loop in Power Automate?